# 3D Model transparency issue

Tags: xna, maya

I am using [Goblin XNA 3.6](https://sourceforge.net/projects/goblinxna/).

When I export a 3D model in FBX format from Maya, the model often looks transparent. For some 3D models it works fine though. What could be causing this?

Comment: We need to know a little bit more about this situation. Where are the models showing up as transparent - in Maya (when it's in FBX format) or in Goblin? Are you sure you're importing everything correctly, and not forgetting to draw textures?

Comment: Is the winding order of all of your vertices the same for each mesh in the model you're exporting?

Comment: Want to show us a picture of what you see in Maya vs in your game? Often the particular appearance can give us clues about the cause of the error.